# Camel simple expression language - How to get property value dynamically

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel and using simple expression to get value from property file in Java DSL.

`.setProperty("PortalUrl", simple("properties:Portal.url"))`

Property file value -
`Portal.url=abc.com/example`

However now i need to get the customer specific URL from property file.
Example values -

`Portal.url.customer1=abc.com/example/abcd
Portal.url.customer2=abc.com/example/xyz`

The customer name comes in the request itself, so i want to do it like
`.setProperty("PortalUrl", simple("properties:Portal.url."+"${body.customerName}"))`

but the above code is not working its giving me the value of the PortalUrl property as `properties:Portal.ulr.customer1`

and when i tried with a direct hard-coded value its giving me the right URL from property file -
`.setProperty("PortalUrl", simple("properties:Portal.url."+"customer1"))`

and it returned correct value - `abc.com/example/abcd`

But i want to get the URL dynamically as par the customer name in incoming request.
Can anyone help me on this, and explain how simple works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with the `${body}` function in the simple language:

```
 .setProperty("PortalUrl", 
     simple("${properties:Portal.url.${body.customerName}}"))
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know you could do that, TIL ^^

Comment: Hi Claus, i also tried this but its not working either, the `${body.customerName}` is getting treated as normal string value and the code is giving error as no value is found for  Portal.url.${body.customerName} in property file.

Comment: It worked for me, which version of Camel are you using?

Comment: I am using - 2.17.0

Comment: It worked for me as well... earlier i missed the starting '$' symbol. ThankYou Claus Ibsen and thankYou Miloš Milivojević :)